# Only run a jQuery animation once, then do other stuff, then reverse the animation

Tags: jquery, animation, menu, logic, unbind

I have a menu with a set of `li`'s which, when hovered over, animates the height of the container and then shows the related child `.subnav`.

**The problems I am having are 2fold.**

1. When I hover over the `li`'s **quickly**, the animation of the container slows down as it is starting the animation again from that point. I would like to be able to say "Only animate this **once** when hovering over any `li`'s" and then return it to it's original position when hovering out of the container or subnav.
2. When the `.subnav` content is showing and I hover over another trigger li, the animation seems to be trying to run on the container again and as such means there is a delay in any actions that are supposed to occur after.

I have tried using `unbind()` and `bind()` but was unsuccessful, I also tried using `:animated` but I can't seem to get the logic right.

Here is my code:

```
var navHeight = $('#primary-nav').height();

$('#primary-nav-list li').hover( function() {
    var elem = $(this);

    if ($(this).is('#roc-noir')){ var subnavHeight = 173; }
    else { var subnavHeight = 235; }

    $('#primary-nav').stop(true,false).animate({height:subnavHeight}, function(){
        $('#primary-nav-list li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $(elem).addClass('active');
        $('#primary-nav-list li').not(this).find('.subnav').fadeOut('fast');
        $(elem).find('.subnav').fadeIn('fast');
    });         
}, function(){
    $('#primary-nav').removeClass('open');
    $('#primary-nav').stop(true,false).animate({height:navHeight}, function(){
        $('#primary-nav-list li').removeClass('active');    
        $('#primary-nav-list li').not(this).find('.subnav').hide();
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the html or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Hover Intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin and see if it does what you need. It adds a slight delay before starting, and subsequently "stopping" the animation.

Comment: Splitting the function into 2 and using hoverIntents 'config' to set a delay actually solved the most prominent problems, the animating of the main nav.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this -- a flag for abort if it is already running?

```
var navHeight = $('#primary-nav').height();

var running = false;

var controller = {
     hoverIn : function() {
       if (running) return;
       running = true;

       var elem = $(this);
       var subnavHeight = 235;

       if ($(this).is('#roc-noir')) { subnavHeight = 173; }

       $('#primary-nav').stop(true,false).animate({height:subnavHeight}, function(){
          $('#primary-nav-list li').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('open');
          $(elem).addClass('active');
          $('#primary-nav-list li').not(this).find('.subnav').fadeOut('fast');
          $(elem).find('.subnav').fadeIn('fast');
       });         
    },
    hoverOut : function(){
       if (running) return;

       $('#primary-nav').removeClass('open');
       $('#primary-nav').stop(true,false).animate({height:navHeight}, function(){
          $('#primary-nav-list li').removeClass('active');    
          $('#primary-nav-list li').not(this).find('.subnav').hide();
          running = false;
       });

    }

$('#primary-nav-list li').hover(controller.hoverIn,controller.hoverOut);
```